# How upload a photo to google drive using url of photo from VK or another social net

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a url of photo from VK. Here is that url:

```
https://sun9-28.userapi.com/impf/c850732/v850732336/16fa43/3b7pxN3vzmI.jpg?size=400x400&quality=96&sign=e43d16ae62020287b2e5ae9073d3f878&c_uniq_tag=5rB9bM19KvnvwLaYvsXilF2uT-MWISzsiNrvNJH65UQ&type=album
```

And i want to upload this image without downloading it to my computer. I did it before by using "requests". My code is below:

```
para = {'name': f'{name_photo}', 'parents': [folder_id]}
files = {'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
       # В запрос вставляем ссылку на фото в интернете и возвращаем в виде контента бинарного кода
       # потому что любой передаваемый файл должен быть в бинарном коде
'file': requests.get(url).content }
requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart',
                                headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'},
                                files=files)
```

And it works, but now i decided to use 'google drive api client' and i have a ploblem because i can't to upload the file. Here is my script

```
file_metadata = {'name': f'{name_photo}.jpg', 'parents': [folder_id]}
media = MediaFileUpload(url,
                        mimetype='image/jpeg')
service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                       media_body=media,
                       fields='id').execute()
```

If i put in "MediaFileUpload" a local file, for example 'files/photo.jpg', i get success, but if i put the url i get an error

```
File "C:\Users\Sverchkov Family\Desktop\Моя учеба\Нетология\Python-разработчик\Basic python\Курсовая работа\Работа с доработаками и клиентской библиотекой гугл\lab_1_renew_by_google_client.py", line 128, in to_google_disk
    media = MediaFileUpload(url,
  File "C:\Users\Sverchkov Family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 131, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sverchkov Family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 593, in __init__
    self._fd = open(self._filename, "rb")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/impf/c850732/v850732336/16fa43/3b7pxN3vzmI.jpg?size=400x400&quality=96&sign=e43d16ae62020287b2e5ae9073d3f878&c_uniq_tag=5rB9bM19KvnvwLaYvsXilF2uT-MWISzsiNrvNJH65UQ&type=album'
```

I don't know how to fix this problem and upload the photo by url. Thanks if you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach which makes use of the `MediaIoBaseUpload`:

```
url = 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/impf/c850732/v850732336/16fa43/3b7pxN3vzmI.jpg?size=400x400&quality=96&sign=e43d16ae62020287b2e5ae9073d3f878&c_uniq_tag=5rB9bM19KvnvwLaYvsXilF2uT-MWISzsiNrvNJH65UQ&type=album'
response = requests.get(url)
file_content = BytesIO(response.content) 
file_metadata = {'name': f'{name_photo}.jpg', 'parents': [folder_id]}
media = MediaIoBaseUpload(file_content, mimetype='image/jpeg')
service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
```

You will still have to use `requests` in order to retrieve the file content but you using the snippet above the upload will be done by using the Python API client library.

#### Reference

- [MediaIoBaseUpload Class](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaIoBaseUpload-class.html).

Comment: You are awesome))) It works. Great job

Answer (score 0):

You cant pass a url to MediaFileUpload, you need to pass the file stream Download the file to your machine first then upload it to drive you cant go from a VK url to drive directly

```
string uploadedFileId;
// Create a new file on Google Drive
await using (var fsSource = new FileStream(UploadFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
      // Create a new file, with metadata and stream.
      var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fsSource, "text/plain");
      request.Fields = "*";
      var results = await request.UploadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

      if (results.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
         {
         Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {results.Exception.Message}");
         }

          // the file id of the new file we created
          uploadedFileId = request.ResponseBody?.Id;
      }
```

Code shamelessly ripped from [How to upload a file to Google Drive with C# .net](https://www.daimto.com/upload-file-to-google-drive/)